# Notation for conditional expectation using integral measure

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation, markov-process

Hi I am struggling to understand this notation for conditional expectation:

(Say $X_{t}$ is a process that takes values in $\mathbb{R}$) then
$$E[f(X_{t})|X_{0}=x]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)p_{t}(x,dy)$$ Where $p_{t}(x,dy)$ is the transition probability function for the process $X_{t}$.

I understand (since $x$ is fixed) $p_{t}(x,dy)$ is a probability measure, but I have not really seen integrals described using measures before...

Comment: If you are familiar with densities, then you can think of it as $\int f(y) p_{t, x}(y) \, dy$ where $p_{t,x}$ is the conditional density of $X_t$ given $X_0 = x$.

Comment: For fixed $x$ let $\mu(A)=p_t(x,A)$. Then $\mu$ is a measure and $\int_{\mathbb R} f(y)p_t(x,dy)$ stands for $\int_{\mathbb R} f d\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

The right side is just a complicated definition for some function of $x$.  And the notation $E[Y \mid X=x] = f(x)$ simply means that $E[Y \mid X] = f(X)$, an (almost sure) equality of random variables.  (Note that the function $f$ is not necessarily unique, so this needs to be taken with a small grain of salt.)